# How to format how values are saved to a text file?

Tags: android, file

I am currently saving values to a text file in my application. The values are read from an EEG headset every second and are then stored within the text file.

The values are read using a **handler** e.g.:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_EEG_POWER:

                eegPower = (TGEegPower) msg.obj;
                //trace code
                Log.d("LSD", "highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
                Log.d("LSD", "highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
                Log.d("LSD", "lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
                Log.d("LSD", "midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
                Log.d("LSD", "delta: " + eegPower.delta);
                Log.d("LSD", "theta: " + eegPower.theta);

                //adding all the EEGpowers to an arraylist to help add them to file
                ArrayList<String> EEGPowers= new ArrayList<String>();

                EEGPowers.add("highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
                EEGPowers.add("lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
                EEGPowers.add("highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
                EEGPowers.add("lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
                EEGPowers.add("lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
                EEGPowers.add("midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
                EEGPowers.add("delta: " + eegPower.delta);
                EEGPowers.add("theta: " + eegPower.theta);

                for(String s: EEGPowers){

                    writeToFileEEGPower(s);

                }
                //rest of handler...
```

The following method is the method used to save the values to file:

```
public void writeToFileEEGPower(String data){

            //creating time for the file 
            Time t= new Time();
            int timeFileSecond= t.second;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "MathsGame" + timeFileSecond + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;

            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

            FileOutputStream os;

            try{

                boolean append= true;

                os= new FileOutputStream(file, append);

                String writeMe =data + "\n";

                os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

                os.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

The method and handler work as is, however my issue is that the values are not formatted as I would like when they are saved and are very messy as you can see:

E.g. of current text file:

[image]

I would like my text file to be formatted **like this:**

[image]

How can I implement this formatting in my code?

EDIT (Attempt at formatting):

```
//Declared globally outside handler
final int maxWordLength = 15;
String spaces[] = new String[maxWordLength];
```

//Within handler:

```
//setting up the array of maxlength etc
                spaces[0] = "";
                for(int i=1; i<maxWordLength ;i++){
                    spaces[i] = spaces[i-1]+" ";
                }

                int seconds=0;

                //CREATING THE HEADER IN THE TEXT FILE 
                writeToFileEEGPower(order("Seconds")+order("highAlpha")+order("lowAlpha")+order("highBeta")+order("LowBeta")+
                        order("lowGamma")+order("midGamma")+order("Delta")+order("Theta")+ "\n");

                //creating the string to be written to file
                String line = order(seconds+"")+order(eegPower.highAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.lowAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.highBeta+"")+
                        order(eegPower.lowBeta+"")+order(eegPower.midGamma+"")+order(eegPower.delta+"")+order(eegPower.theta+"")+ "\n";

                //write the string to file
                writeToFileEEGPower(line);
```

Current sample output in text file:

[image]

Comment: Put the data into a [table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html), and display that.

Comment: I seen that being mentioned before but how would i implement it in the activty, then transfer it to the txt file?

Comment: Your question is badly worded - there is no need to "format the text file". Instead you want to format how the data is displayed on screen. As a followup to the comment from Robert Harvey, look at TableLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: @bigcoder995 : "how would i implement it in the activty, then transfer it to the txt file?" - You don't... you display it in the `Activity` and write to the text file at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, so it the data being written to the text file as a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your max 'word' length, and complete every 'word' with empty spaces.

for example:

#### STEP 1

Define maxWordLength. this value describe the width of each column. Should this value will be slightly larger than the longest word (In this example length of 'highAlpha:'=10, choose number>10).

```
final int maxWordLength = 15;
```

#### STEP 2

Create array of empty spaces.

```
String spaces[] = {""," ","   ","    ","     ", /*....*/ "               "};// Complete the missing words up to the last word with 15 spaces.
```

Or create it dynamically:

```
String spaces[] = new String[maxWordLength];
spaces[0] = "";
for(int i=1; i<maxWordLength ;i++){
    spaces[i] = spaces[i-1]+" ";
}
```

#### STEP 3

Define the 'Seconds' var, create the order function at your class and write the header row to the file:

```
int seconds=0;
```

//table header row
    writeToFileEEGPower(order("Seconds")+order("highAlpha")+order("lowAlpha")+order("highBeta")/*+...*/);

```
private String order(String value){

    return (value + spaces[maxWordLength-value.length()]);
}
```

#### STEP 4

For each handleMessage create a line and save it to the file:

```
String line = order(seconds+"")+order(eegPower.highAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.lowAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.highBeta+"")//+...;

writeToFileEEGPower(line);
```

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean by max word length?, Am I then adding the return value of the Order method (a string) to the writeToFile method?

Comment: I edited the post. If you have more questions I will answer happily!

Comment: Thank you for you help it is most appreciated. Is it possible to format the file as I shown in the question, i.e. with the values horizontally across the page and the seconds also included?

Comment: I edited the post again. It should look like you want.

Comment: I am getting an issue that the header is generated every time the values are generated?

Comment: I have added an EDIT to the question, can you please look at it. I think the issue is that the Theta value is not being displayed, and also the numbers are not correctly alligned under their headers, thanks for your help

Comment: STEP 1+2+3 should not be in your handler method. It should be on your class constructor or in Handler constructor (you can override it). stackoverflow platforn does not allow to display multiple spaces, and as a result can not see your output correctly. please open your output text file with notepad++, capture the screen and attach result.